# Let $R$ a ring prove that $x(y-z)=xy - xz$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $R$ a ring (not necessarily commutative) prove that $x(y-z)=xy - xz$.

\begin{align*}
x(y-z)&=x(y+(-z)) \\ 
&=xy +x(-z) \\
&=xy+-(xz) \\
&=xy-xz
\end{align*}

I think all my steps are valid, but I however don't see why:

1. $a-b=a+(-b)$
2. $x(-z)=-(xz)$

How can I show this rigoursly ? I was thinking that 1) may be a definition.

Comment: I know the definition of a ring. @DietrichBurde

Comment: The first one is a definition. We define $a-b$ as the sum $a+(-b)$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde I don't see anywhere defined that $a-b=a+(-b)$

Comment: @DietrichBurde I see that answer. And I'm aware of that definition. But doesn't define an binary operation $-:R×R→R: (a,b) ↦ a-b = a + (-b) $ Right ?

Comment: "Some basic properties of a ring follow immediately from the axioms.
The additive identity and the additive inverse are unique."

Comment: ^That's from wikipedia. Once we have established that the additive identity is unique, **then** we may (well-)define "subtraction"...

Comment: Suppose you wrote the axioms for a group using "addition" as the operation suppressed instead of "multiplication".  That is, every group has an "addition" operation.  Or equivalently xy means (x+y).  Then, the inverse axiom for groups says "for all x, there exists a -x such that x-x=0."  Again, I've suppressed the addition operation, so x-x=0 implicitly best gets read as meaning (x+-x)=0.  So, no, you don't need to define a binary operation of subtraction for this sort of problem.  You just need to recognize that x(y-z) has multiplication suppressed first and addition suppressed second.

Comment: @DougSpoonwood Ah, that makes sense. Didn't think about it that way. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

1. $a-b=a+(-b)$ by the definition of subtraction.
2. $x(-z)+xz={?}$.

Comment: $x(-z)+xz=x(-z+z)=x⋅0=0$. aaaaah ! thanks

Comment: @90intuition you mean $=x\cdot0=0$

Comment: I edited it now.

Answer (score 1):

From Wikipedia:

*For each $a$ in $R$ there exists $−a$ in $R$ such that $a + (−a) = (−a) + a = 0$ ($−a$ is the inverse element of $a$)*

$$
x(y-z)=x(y+(-z))
$$

*Multiplication distributes over addition:*

$$\begin{align}
x(y+(-z))&=xy+x(-z)\\
&=xy-xz,\qquad\text{ as above.}
\end{align}$$

Comment: That definition doesn't define an binary operation "substraction", right ? Something like: $-:R×R→R: (a,b) ↦ a-b = a + (-b)$