# How to prove $x-y = x+(-y)$ in ring theory.

Tags: ring-theory, notation

Okay, I have talked with a lot of people about this silly question. And I have thought about this way longer than is good for me. Everybody seem to disagree with me, and that is the reason I think I can't get this out of my head, because I feel like pure mathematically I'm right.

If you look at the expression $x - y$ in ring theory. What does this mean? Okay of course, everybody here knows/agrees that this mean $x+(-y)$. Where $-y$ is the additive inverse of $-y$. And $+$ the binary operation "addition".

So what is your problem Kasper ? Well, if you just look at the definitions in ring theory, then I wouldn't be able to conclude this. There is no definition saying that $x-y=x+(-y)$ (in the book I read about ring theory). What I am able to conclude, is that if I define $z=-y$. Then:

$$x{-y}=xz=x⋅z=x⋅-y$$

Because it is defined (at least in my book) that $x\cdot y =xy$ where "$⋅$" is the binary operation "multiplication". As the symbol "$-$" is only defined in the context of $-x$ being the additive inverse of $x$, this is the only conclussion I can logically find.

Talking with other mathematicians I get the impression I'm a little bit alone in this view, but I think I should be able to justify every step in a math proof, using definitions/theorems/axioms etc. And I shouldn't justify my step because I know already since highschool what is meant with $x-y$. Being able to trace back every math proof to axioms and definitions is part of the beauty of math in my opinion.

So, I would say you need to define "$-$" in the context of $-x$ (unary operation) where it denotes the additive inverse, and define "$-$" in the context of $x-y$ (binary operation) where it denotes $x+(-y)$. But I talk to my teacher, he says, no in ring theory you only need "$-$" as an unary operation. If I talk here in chatroom, they tell me the same.

---

Okay, going even deeper in this problem then it is good for me. In a comment in other question:

> Suppose you wrote the axioms for a group using "addition" as the
>   operation suppressed instead of "multiplication". That is, every group
>   has an "addition" operation. Or equivalently xy means (x+y). Then, the
>   inverse axiom for groups says "for all x, there exists a -x such that
>   x-x=0." Again, I've suppressed the addition operation, so x-x=0
>   implicitly best gets read as meaning (x+-x)=0. So, no, you don't need
>   to define a binary operation of subtraction for this sort of problem.
>   You just need to recognize that x(y-z) has multiplication suppressed
>   first and addition suppressed second.

This makes a little bit sense to me, but still. If you look at groups, and write $xy=x+y$, then you also write $x^{-1}$ instead of $-x$. And in ring theory they define $xy=x⋅y$ not $xy=x+y$ (at least in my book).

Comment: You must distinguish between the binary operation $x - y$ and the unary operation $-y$. Just because they use the same symbol doesn't mean they're the same.

Comment: @DanielFischer I know it is a long post, but I think that is exactly what I wrote: "So, I would say you need to define "$-$" in the context of $-x$ (unary operation) where it denotes the additive inverse, and define "$-$" in the context of $x-y$ (binary operation) where it denotes $x+(-y)$. But I talk to my teacher, he says, no in ring theory you only need "$-$" as an unary operation. If I talk here in chatroom, they tell me the same.  "

Comment: I agree with you. You need to define the binary operation. As Brian wrote, it's just a convenience, so you don't really _need_ to define it, but if you haven't defined it, you can't use it.

Comment: It's not an error in definitions. It's just a matter of convenience; we don't define $x-y := x+(-y)$ because it's generally understood that's what we mean.

Comment: @Mike Well in that case. Just don't define $-x$ as well, because we all know what that means.

Comment: @DanielFischer "But if you haven't defined it, you can't use it." Yes. Somebody that agrees with me. Now I can sleep. :)

Comment: @Kasper Where "defining" most often means a statement like "one writes $a-b$ for $a+(-b)$" in the context of abelian groups, or so. Not a definition with a number in the main text ;)

Comment: @DanielFischer Yes, giving it a number may be overkill ;) Allthough I would like to be able to write:
$$x-y = x+(-y) \;\;\;\; \text{by definition 1.1.1}$$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Edited to match revised question.**

When $x-y$ is defined, it is of course defined to be $x+(-y)$, but we often don’t bother to define it. After all, there is no actual need to define subtraction in a ring: it’s just a convenience, and you can do everything without it. Yes, a careful author of a textbook would explicitly define $x-y$ if he planned to use the notation, but failure to do so is a pretty minor failing: the definition is easy to pick up from context even if it’s not stated explicitly. I’d even go so far as to say that learning to pick things up from context is part of learning to read mathematics as it is actually written.

Comment: I edited my question. It is not defined in my book. And not defined in 2 other books I've read about ring theory. That is my whole point. I feel like it should be defined.

Comment: @Kasper: If the subtraction operation is going to be used in an elementary text, I agree that it ought to be defined. However, I also think that even if the author fails to define it explicitly, students should have no trouble picking up from context what is meant.

Comment: I'm not worried that any student has trouble picking up from context what is meant. It is just something inside my saying that in math, you should be able to trace back every proof to the axioms and definitions. If you can't do that. You should add a definition. I mean, if I don't define $-x$ as the additive inverse of $x$. I don't think many student has problem with that as well. But not defining sucht things, disrupts the beauty of math in my view.

Comment: I think I disagree a little bit. I think it should be clear to the student what is defined, and what should be proved. I don't want to feel like that there all hidden definitions around everywhere. Otherwise, if I have hard time proving $0x=0$, I may easily conclude that this is probably a definition that is not given in the text. Now I know, okay it is not a definition or axiom, and we haven't proved it already, so if I want to use $0x=0$, I should justify it.

Comment: @Kasper: The two aren’t really comparable: $0\cdot x=0$ is a statement about defined entities, while $x-y$ introduces a new entity, the binary operation $-$. The former is either an unstated axiom, in which case the author has made a serious blunder, or an assertion requiring proof; the latter can only be understood as introducing a new operation whose definition has (unfortunately) been omitted because the author was a little careless or is counting on students to pick it up on their own.

Comment: Well, I'm sure for you that is directly clear. And when me and friend yesterday asked how to prove that $a-b=a+(-b)$. I said that I thought that I need a binary operation $-$. I got told that this follows from the definition of $-a$ and that you need to define a binary operation $-$ by 2 high rep people. Now, when I asked it in the chatbox, a 40k+ user tells me that $-$ is not a binary operation, only a unary operation in ring theory. And when I tell I feel like I need to define $-$ as binary operation they tell me I'm stubborn and making problems that don't exists.

Comment: I think this confusion just comes from the fact that if something is not defined, people are convinced that it doesn't need to be defined for some reason. And they come with all kind of reasons why it is not defined. One tells me that $x-y$ is not a binary operation for (this)[http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/527682/let-r-a-ring-prove-that-xy-z-xy-xz#comment1128303_527682] reason.

Comment: @Kasper: The point is that you don’t need to prove that $a-b=a+(-b)$: that is the **definition** of $a-b$. You’re quite right that it’s a binary operation, but you don’t need some separate definition: that **is** the definition. Anyone who told you that $-$ is not a binary operation in the expression $a-b$ is simply wrong.

Comment: @Kasper: Are you talking about Doug Spoonwood’s comment? Ignore it: he is, unfortunately, a rather unreliable source of information.

Comment: Yes I was talking about Doug Spoonwood's comment. Okay, I'm finally getting satsfied with this matter. I really need to go to bed now. Thanks for helping me out :)

Comment: @Kasper: You’re welcome; get some sleep!

Comment: Ohh now, at the chat they still don't agree. They say: "You needn't define a "new" binary operation. The binary operation $+(a,b)=a+b$ and the unary opereation $-(y)=-y$ are already defined. That's all you need."

Comment: @Kasper: They’re all you need in order to do ring theory, but if you intend to write $a-b$, you need to define the binary operation that you’re writing.

Answer (score 5):

You need *some* definition of $x-y$ to prove anything about it.

It is most common, at the level where you can speak about abstract rings, to *define* $x-y$ to mean $x+(-y)$, as Brian writes.

But you can also use the grade-school definition: $x-y$ means the unique $a$ that solves $a+y=x$. We can then prove that $x+(-y)$ satisfies this definition:

$$ (x+(-y))+y = x+((-y)+y) = x+0 = x $$

and also that any solution to this equation must be unique, because if $a+y=x$ and $b+y=x$, then we have $a+y=b+y$, and then

$$ a = a+0 = a+(y+(-y)) = (a+y)+(-y) = (b+y)+(-y) = b+(y+(-y)) = b+0 = b $$